# the action view does not take the layout zend framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, layout, action

i have contact us controller , that has a form submitted to send action , so after submitting the link is , contactus/send/

you can see the full layout design in contactus index view , but when i call the action , it seems he can't see the layout , and represent only as text with no css or javascript.

Comment: well , that was the basUrl() helper that included in the header , it get the wrong url  ,so the view for the actions can't see the stylesheet paths and get them wrong

Comment: Plz post the layout, the sendAction and both view scripts.